# How to perform an action when an error occurs in the itertuple loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I have the code below running fine. However, when an error occurs on the interaction page, the robot stops and takes no action.

I need that in case of any error, example: The url in question is down,
I need the robot to stop and close the browser.

I tried to use

```
While True:
      try:
      except:
```

But when a page error occurred, the robot just stopped and did not close the browser

```
for row in df2.itertuples():
    r.frame('ifrm-pdr-portal')
    r.type('sc_clone_placa', row[1])
    r.type('id_sc_field_renavam', str(row[2]))
    r.click('sub_form_b')
    r.wait(10.0)
    p.scroll(-1400)
    r.wait(5.0)
    localPesq4 = p.locateOnScreen('GerarGuia.PNG', confidence=0.9)
    if localPesq4:
        r.frame('ifrm-pdr-portal')
        r.click('sc_pagar_bot')
        r.wait(5.0)
        r.frame('ifrm-pdr-portal')
        r.click('sc_download_bot')
        r.wait(5.0)
        janela = p.getActiveWindow()
        janela.maximize()
        p.sleep(2)
        p.click(x=391, y=36)
        p.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
        url = pyperclip.paste()
        text = row[1] + str(row[2]) + '.pdf'
        r.download(url, text)
        upload_file = text
        gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '11SsSKYEATgn_VWzSb-8RjRL-VoIxvamC'}]})
        gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
        gfile.Upload()
        extrpdf = extract_text(text)
        new_csv = 'dados.csv'
        with open(new_csv, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            file_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar=' ')
            file_writer.writerow(extrpdf)
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        with open('dados.csv', 'r') as f:
            for row2 in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar=' '):
                try:
                    ws.append(row2)
                except IllegalCharacterError:
                    ws.append([str(i).encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8') for i in row2])
        wb.save('dados.xlsx')
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('dados.xlsx')
        sheet = wb.active
        venc = sheet['A25'].value
        valor = sheet['A24'].value
        p.sleep(1)
        worksheet.update('C' + str(lastRow + 1), [[venc, valor]])
        p.click(x=368, y=87)
        janela = p.getActiveWindow()
        janela.close()
        p.sleep(2)
        r.close()
        r.init()
        r.url('https://www.meudetran.ms.gov.br/veiculo.php#')
        p.sleep(2)
        janela = p.getActiveWindow()
        janela.maximize()
        p.sleep(2)
    else:
        r.close()
        r.init()
        r.url('https://www.meudetran.ms.gov.br/veiculo.php#')
        p.sleep(2)
        janela = p.getActiveWindow()
        janela.maximize()
        p.sleep(2)
p.sleep(5)
r.close()
```

**SOLUTION**

I added 'try:' under the tuple and at the end I inserted an 'except: break'

```
for row in df2.itertuples():
    try:
       #My lines code
    except:
        print('error')
        break
```

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: The example would be: The robot opens the first page of the url: https://www.meudetran.ms.gov.br/veiculo.php
Fill in the fields Placa and Renavam. On the next page, it is blank and the robot does not find the 'GerarGuia' button.
Instead of closing the browser and stopping the operation, it leaves it open and stops

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could try to use `except Exception as ex: print('error', ex)` to get more information about problem. And if error show what type of eception it raised then you could use this exception instead of `Exception` to display even more detailed information.

Comment: In addition to what furas has said, you should also try to localize the try/except as much as possible. There's too much unknown global scope for me to really read your code, so I can't help much. Boa sorte.